# Order by using selected values from drop down list without using form

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

Searched many options to find some easy solution where i can sort my results but din't find any.
I want to order the displayed results by selected drop down values. I don't want to use "form". Want the other way to sort it.

```
<div class="col-lg-2">
<label class="margin-bottom:25px;" style="margin-left:75px;"> Sort by: <label>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-2">
    <select class="form-control" id="sortby" name="sortby">
        <option selected value="ID">ID</option>
        <option value="Name">Name</option>
        <option value="Source">Source</option>
        <option value="Location">Location</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

The above is my drop down list.
The below is our $sql initial query :

```
$condition = implode(' AND ', $query);
$sql = " SELECT candidate.cand_number,candidate.cand_fname,candidate.cand_source,candidate_contact.cand_location FROM candidate ".$join.' where '.$condition;
```

Now we have tried to this so far ,but it seems something is wrong.

```
if($_POST['sortby']=="ID")
{
 $sql = " SELECT candidate.cand_number,candidate.cand_fname,candidate.cand_source,candidate_contact.cand_location FROM candidate ".$join.' where '.$condition." order by candidate.cand_number asc";
}

if($_POST['sortby']=="Name")
{
 $sql = " SELECT candidate.cand_number,candidate.cand_fname,candidate.cand_source,candidate_contact.cand_location FROM candidate ".$join.' where '.$condition." order by candidate.cand_fname asc";
}

if($_POST['sortby']=="Source")
{
 $sql = " SELECT candidate.cand_number,candidate.cand_fname,candidate.cand_source,candidate_contact.cand_source FROM candidate ".$join.' where '.$condition." order by candidate.cand_source asc";
}

if($_POST['sortby']=="Location")
{
 $sql = " SELECT candidate.cand_number,candidate.cand_fname,candidate.cand_source,candidate_contact.cand_source FROM candidate_contact ".$join.' where '.$condition." order by candidate.cand_location asc";
}
```

asc- Its for ordering in ascending order;

My jquery/ajax script-

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            // Each time you change your sort list, send AJAX request
            $("#sortby").change(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "viewcandidate.php",
                    data: { sortby:$("#sortby").val() }
                })
                // Copy the AJAX response in the table
                .done(function( msg ) {
                    $("#list").html(msg);
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    //even tried with $(window).load(function){.....but no result.
```

What is wrong as this is not working for me ? I dont want to use form. Suggest me some easy solution.

Comment: you can use ajax for this

Comment: @saty.can u explain with some skeleton or code. Much appreciated for me !

Comment: "There is something wrong" > Is there any error ? Could you describe a little bit more what you see ?

Comment: @Cr3aHal0...my first sql query is successful i.e its success for me...I want only the solution or some suggest on my Order by and the later IF conditions I have used. Thank You.

Comment: First off, the way you are appending to your SQL queries is wide open to injection if `$condition` or `$query` are coming from user input (even if it is a value from a drop down, users can still send any POST values they like). Also there seems to be an error in your HTML `<option value="Relevance">Name</option> <option value="Name">Source</option>` whereas your PHP looks for `$_POST['sortby']` to be "ID", "Name" or "Source".

Comment: @OhAuth..Ok ..i did the correction...but not success..

Comment: @Yamiko..added jquery. Check to edit post.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly Here something wrong...

```
<select class="form-control" id="sortby" name="sortby">
    <option selected value="ID">ID</option>
    <option value="Relevance">Name</option><!-- Value ???-->
    <option value="Name">Source</option><!-- Value ???-->
</select>
```

would be like

```
<select class="form-control" id="sortby" name="sortby">
    <option selected value="ID">ID</option>
    <option value="Name">Name</option>
    <option value="Source">Source</option>
</select>
```

As you compare like $_POST['sortby']=="Name" and $_POST['sortby']=="Source"

Comment: @user3419778...Thank You..I did the corrections. But its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a blank space before the order by.

```
$sql = " SELECT candidate.cand_number,candidate.cand_fname,candidate.cand_source 
FROM candidate ".$join.' where '.$condition." order by candidate.cand_number" ;
```

Comment: @jpintor..I did the above as well as yours correction..But no success here.

Answer (score 0):

Your drop-down list is this :

```
<select class="form-control" id="sortby" name="sortby">
    <option selected value="ID">ID</option>
    <option value="Relevance">Name</option>
    <option value="Name">Source</option>
</select>
```

When you post a drop-down list, the value will be the value="..." attribute of the selected option, not the text displayed.

So your 'sortby' conditions are not good, it must be :

```
if($_POST['sortby']=="ID")
{
 $sql = " SELECT candidate.cand_number,candidate.cand_fname,candidate.cand_source FROM candidate ".$join.' where '.$condition." order by candidate.cand_number" ;
}

if($_POST['sortby']=="Relevance")
{
 $sql = " SELECT candidate.cand_number,candidate.cand_fname,candidate.cand_source FROM candidate ".$join.' where '.$condition." order by candidate.cand_fname" ;
}

if($_POST['sortby']=="Name")
{
 $sql = " SELECT candidate.cand_number,candidate.cand_fname,candidate.cand_source FROM candidate ".$join.' where '.$condition." order by candidate.cand_Source" ;
}
```

Comment: @MaximeMettey..I did as told by you..but no result.

Comment: @CodeSniper Is your drop-down list posted (using AJAX or not) to refresh your list ?

Comment: @MaimeMettey..The drop down is to order the contents displayed after my search result..for ex: If I order it by "Name"-the contents should get in alphabetically order. I have not used AJAX OR Jquery for this.

Answer (score 0):

@CodeSniper..try to check some spaces. I am sure you will get the solution with this.

Answer (score 0):

I made a small example to show you how to use jQuery to dynamically reload your data. Of course, you will have to adapt this to your case.

For this example I am using my localhost, with database = 'test' and a table named 'candidate' with three columns : ID, Name and Source.

There are two files : index.php and request.php (in the same folder).

index.php file :

```
<?php
    // Database connection
    $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'test');
    // First request, on load
    $sql = "SELECT ID, Name, Source FROM candidate";
    $exe = $db->query($sql);
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Including jQuery -->
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <!-- Generate table on load -->
            <table border="1">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Source</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="list">
                    <?php
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($exe)) {
                            echo "
                                <tr>
                                    <td>".$row['ID']."</td>
                                    <td>".$row['Name']."</td>
                                    <td>".$row['Source']."</td>
                                </tr>";
                        }
                    ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            Sort by :
            <select class="form-control" id="sortby" name="sortby">
                <option selected value="ID">ID</option>
                <option value="Name">Name</option>
                <option value="Source">Source</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                // Each time you change your sort list, send AJAX request
                $("#sortby").change(function(){
                    $.ajax({
                        method: "POST",
                        url: "request.php",
                        data: { sortby:$("#sortby").val() }
                    })
                    // Copy the AJAX response in the table
                    .done(function( msg ) {
                        $("#list").html(msg);
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

request.php file :

```
<?php

$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'test');

if(isset($_POST['sortby'])) {
    if($_POST['sortby'] == "ID") {
        $sql = "SELECT ID, Name, Source FROM candidate ORDER BY ID";
    } else if($_POST['sortby'] == "Name") {
        $sql = "SELECT ID, Name, Source FROM candidate ORDER BY Name";
    } else if($_POST['sortby'] == "Source") {
        $sql = "SELECT ID, Name, Source FROM candidate ORDER BY Source";
    }
} else {
    $sql = "SELECT ID, Name, Source FROM candidate";
}

$exe = $db->query($sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($exe)) {
    echo "
        <tr>
            <td>".$row['ID']."</td>
            <td>".$row['Name']."</td>
            <td>".$row['Source']."</td>
        </tr>";
}

?>
```

Demo : http://maxime-mettey.com/projects/dropdownajax/

Dowload files : http://maxime-mettey.com/projects/dropdownajax/dropdownajax.zip

Comment: Did you get a result with this ?

Comment: See i have done some editing to my post. Now suggest me some solution. I think I am going wrong with ajax/jquery code.

Comment: @CodeSniper Your jQuery code seems good, just one thing : do you have an HTML tag with `id="list"` ? Because `$("#list").html(msg);` will write the result of the `viewcandidate.php` file in the HTML tag with `id="list"`.

Comment: After that, if it still does not work, is your application online so I could check console errors ? If not, you can try your application on Google Chrome browser : load your page; open the console (F12); click on "Network" tab; click on filter icon if it is not checked; click on "XHR" filter; Select a value in the drop down list of your page and check if viewcandidate.php is called in the XHR list; If it is the case, click on it and click on response to see what the script is returning.

Comment: @MaximeMettey..the id="list" I dint find this..as this code was written by another fellow with me. shall I remove this part ? And I will follow the chrome steps too. Let you know soon.

Comment: @MaximeMettey..I did follow your steps of chrome browser. When I select  the one of the values,the XHR does not show any things but its a blank. No response in XHR.

Comment: @MaximeMettey..the above post codes is in viewcandidate.php and this page contains output displayed by previous search results in tabular format.. and I am ordering the result in the same page i.e viewcandidate.php. Everything I am doing is in same page.

Comment: @CodeSniper You need to have a separate PHP page to do your AJAX requests, like I did in my example : you have one main page where you have your HTML and your jQuery code, and one PHP page where you execute your SQL requests and print/echo the result you want in your main page. Then, the printed result will be inserted into the block you specify here : `$("#list").html(msg);`. It can be `$('#yourHtmlID')`, where `yourHtmlId` is the id attribute of the HTML block you want to reload. I will try to put my example online in a few hours (after work) to show you how it is made.

Comment: I put my example online here : http://maxime-mettey.com/projects/dropdownajax/ is it what you want to do ?

Comment: @MaximeMettey..Thank You...i will follow this ..and let you know soon. :) Can you drop your code or post your code of that maxime-mettey.com/projects/dropdownajax, so that i would have a look on it. It is possible for you.

Comment: I made a ZIP archive containing my two PHP files and an SQL file with my `candidate` table : http://maxime-mettey.com/projects/dropdownajax/dropdownajax.zip